# Requesting assistance in SQL query

Tags: sql

I have tried almost everything to my knowledge. How can I get the below expected result from the table llattrdata?

[image: Original table and expected data]

Comment: What product are you using: MS Sql Server, Oracle, MySQL....?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt. (And don't forget to read [mcve].)

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below option-

```
SELECT A. ID,
(SELECT B.VALSTR FROM your_table B WHERE B.ID = A.ID AND B.ATTRID = 2) V1,
(SELECT B.VALSTR FROM your_table B WHERE B.ID = A.ID AND B.ATTRID = 3) V2,
(SELECT B.VALSTR FROM your_table B WHERE B.ID = A.ID AND B.ATTRID = 4) V3
FROM your_table A
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want conditional aggregation.  I would guess:

```
select id,
       max(case when attrid = 2 then valstr end) as v1,
       max(case when attrid = 3 then valstr end) as v2,
       max(case when attrid = 4 then valstr end) as v3
from t
group by id
```